# Plotting spatial-temporal model predictions

Tags: r

I have the following model for which i am trying to plot predictions so to analyse the spatial-temporal trends over the years of my data (2012-2014).

```
mod = gam(TB ~ offset(log(Population)) + s(Indigenous, k = 10, bs = "cr") + s(Urbanisation, k = 10, bs = "cr") +
              s(Density, k = 10, bs = "cr") + Poverty + s(Poor_Sanitation, k = 10, bs = "cr") + Unemployment + Timeliness +
              as.factor(Year) + Region + s(lon, lat), 
              data = TBdata, 
              family = nb(link = 'log'))
```

Currently I have used the following code to plot my model but this doesn't give me temporal trends (just one plot not split by year), i also think this is just plotting my smooth function of lon and lat. If anyone knows how to correctly plot the predictions of this model so i can get the spatial-temporal trends that would be great (ggplot preferred by any method is fine).

my current plot

```
plot(mod, contour.col = 'white', too.far = 0.10, scheme = 2, rug = F)
```

output

[image]

data snipet

```
TBdata %>% as.data.frame()
    Indigenous Illiteracy Urbanisation   Density  Poverty Poor_Sanitation Unemployment Timeliness Year   TB Population Region       lon         lat
1   0.33498668   6.354471     84.10664 0.7135083 31.27839       15.269975     5.411208   59.23954 2012  323     559543  11001 -60.67326 -12.1375562
2   6.44677661   8.493550     71.36292 0.7429604 48.59763       29.364664     5.916373   58.06452 2012   15      73193  11002 -64.02859  -9.4315409
3   0.16009349  10.211680     66.96757 0.6638205 42.28298       31.923537     4.084887   88.65248 2012   47     176003  11003 -62.35638 -10.6366765
4   0.54930178  10.294286     68.67525 0.5951172 38.89858       28.534552     5.497259   75.15528 2012   45     294157  11004 -64.09781 -11.6949147
5   0.31773624  11.418378     42.84595 0.6385168 51.57131       48.406288     4.035860   58.33333 2012   17      69841  11005 -61.21610 -13.1534602
6   1.02317144  10.267994     66.49738 0.5946587 39.10929       29.287196     5.578758   69.31818 2012   66     228654  11006 -61.68878 -11.9327327
7   0.82154405   7.811040     82.75737 0.5927965 31.71298       12.124683     6.040940   88.76404 2012   24     136730  11007 -62.56662  -9.6590901
8   0.11125568  11.782911     65.34103 0.5550268 40.84772       29.258613     5.059368   41.17647 2012    5      51890  11008 -62.88370 -11.6058899
9   3.26071252  22.840871     57.55142 1.0104743 60.54176       32.830252     6.722286   50.00000 2012   59     135803  12001 -71.12488  -8.6984193
10  8.27981067  32.395581     51.29996 1.2319246 65.52161       44.536382     4.761273   45.00000 2012   13      76221  12002 -69.65906  -9.6142587
11  7.81641388  26.125845     63.67133 1.0323498 58.63709       35.371653     7.526261   58.33333 2012   13      52651  12003 -67.92047  -9.9827217
12  0.18487825  11.014522     83.02779 0.7966288 42.60303       11.748025     8.647023   31.61616 2012  246     433224  12004 -72.86194  -8.2736825
13  1.23080070  19.107763     66.32175 0.8262261 55.68908       28.966361     5.895377   70.90909 2012   19      60887  12005 -69.15972 -10.7140791
14 50.64622783  23.387271     48.26342 1.4629935 48.07222       45.458143     7.683733   36.09023 2012   48      99826  13001 -65.46983  -4.0204889
15 10.04667257  21.056304     48.48717 1.5299792 72.38631       47.042878    15.439268    0.00000 2012    0      25044  13002 -59.92364  -1.5879241
16 27.62278330  21.747460     58.06581 1.4155145 70.70161       39.524745     6.358736   43.02326 2012  103     231482  13003 -65.13166  -0.3415058
17  4.30755994  33.107526     62.22066 1.1412305 72.10023       40.095659     6.539286   48.36066 2012   42     131695  13004 -65.10241  -7.1406849
18  3.01262696  15.785024     74.05870 1.2235418 66.95602       20.833828     5.363723   30.39216 2012   43      87520  13005 -58.19999  -2.9087320
19  0.94701077  18.122909     60.82228 1.1627655 66.90984       35.127488     9.134779   39.74359 2012   46     156671  13006 -60.24980  -3.3062838
 20  0.65529611   4.908563     93.81673 0.8593049 41.11021        4.893957    10.483849   75.53917 2012 1829    2106861  13007 -60.54443  -6.6830480
21  1.35932242   9.200504     47.65380 0.8861087 55.57790       37.740240    10.428850   50.00000 2012   32      55600  13008 -68.71086  -5.9785253
22  0.64001789   9.758551     60.98325 1.1415410 67.23815       30.632589     8.406879   59.20398 2012   51     156384  13009 -67.55678  -1.8679793
23  5.00288446   8.046211     57.06692 1.2392834 73.76746       35.573960     7.824595   45.21452 2012   77     248506  13010 -58.56150  -3.1484377
24  5.98590106  27.766366     58.63355 1.1346604 71.10207       39.876155     8.986358   46.00000 2012   22      49500  13011 -63.22067  -4.1223522
25  7.64428333  29.406475     59.70856 1.0691215 70.59885       42.578621     6.897342   54.79452 2012   12      70911  13012 -68.14551  -8.1089091
26  6.27901221  16.298789     54.29879 1.1055992 65.44075       42.302509     8.442431   40.58824 2012   56     170985  13013 -69.69795  -4.7593017
27  8.39040188   8.206571     89.95105 0.7979057 38.37151        6.075713     7.358698   64.10891 2012   91     334076  14001 -60.49593   0.3182771
28 44.71062619  17.073994     22.33634 1.3535825 57.66587       48.465597     9.245283   53.84615 2012   11      44023  14002 -60.24954   3.4039662
29  6.18822518  18.247396     57.11455 0.9473904 53.79555       32.518013     8.424442   40.00000 2012    7      43635  14003 -61.74950   1.4791942
30  2.83585991  13.326820     50.54670 0.8424786 56.25717       31.095345     6.860730   68.75000 2012   12      47790  14004 -62.22345   3.4860616
31  2.09288322  10.842066     53.12386 1.1715843 70.29388       31.457975     7.813915   46.47887 2012   40     189429  15001 -49.92266  -4.5450924
32  0.63918534  10.374821     60.78618 0.9561001 62.77747       27.277026     7.956556   43.20988 2012  131     492734  15002 -48.68255  -2.5733129
33  1.21355631  17.414926     51.12920 1.2375818 65.28844       36.654216     8.156438   56.09756 2012   14      69092  15003 -51.95188  -7.4381955
34  0.01616554  28.968886     38.94816 1.6750609 77.88347       57.851494     9.060787   54.28571 2012   22     135041  15004 -54.65470  -1.8714902
35  0.03968371  24.890572     42.31165 1.4990517 75.79085       55.581917     7.924278   63.28125 2012   38     209923  15005 -47.77654  -0.8198963
36  0.04052552  13.905926     48.69076 1.1558360 71.62642       38.544809     8.836839   43.43434 2012   36     158333  15006 -49.59232  -7.1006744
37  0.16146379   3.754233     94.76295 0.7778492 40.30134        2.661756    10.683572   62.49457 2012 1880    2185084  15007 -51.01589  -2.1353053
38  0.08202806   9.219135     75.28922 0.8238219 57.50873       14.657248     8.974412   52.50836 2012  185     305405  15008 -50.15950  -6.3840531
39  0.05947901  11.416480     53.22522 0.9225446 67.27691       15.432007     6.932257   37.11656 2012  110     251888  15009 -48.05151  -3.8479350
40  0.08125090  17.971794     56.30766 0.8787671 69.37043       25.782833     7.573189   36.34204 2012  131     390863  15010 -56.87939  -0.1044528
41  0.03864606  13.744725     49.50903 1.2463430 74.00576       42.667051     7.309062   75.55556 2012  101     449907  15011 -49.66102  -5.6414827
42  0.23364324  17.398443     49.76983 1.1178318 68.50080       36.631718     9.384440   55.00000 2012   88     299079  15012 -56.42347  -6.4524857
43  0.23725366  22.500687     38.31865 0.9708972 74.23657       39.255409     5.860432   49.11504 2012   81     441719  15013 -47.18900  -2.0744028
44  4.24519522  15.341410     56.05853 0.8841889 56.77666       32.751180     6.477704   34.27419 2012   72     240165  15014 -50.37440  -0.8876770
45  1.87527384  16.205226     58.56287 0.8116198 54.69351       38.918163     5.465688   56.88073 2012   67     283554  15015 -50.19400  -8.7018861
46  0.52965071  16.844620     67.98471 0.8407914 62.00125       27.628233     9.747115   60.46512 2012   68     340793  15016 -48.03117  -1.3843356
47  0.67886709  16.821733     71.07965 0.8295509 59.87976       19.369363    10.857736   67.46411 2012   71     306994  15017 -49.53206  -2.3657026
48  2.54441144  12.853355     57.68736 0.8028324 50.58523       36.205599     7.418385   57.42574 2012   50     177935  15018 -47.07320  -1.1491093
49  0.51103595  10.931050     75.61964 0.7753638 45.60888       17.048489    10.320373   54.72441 2012   66     271172  15019 -48.49396  -1.3613721
50  0.18999389  13.147962     74.79087 0.7868254 50.54423       19.089217     9.036023   66.66667 2012   85     295238  15020 -49.36448  -0.5230343
51  0.50384846  14.530229     75.98996 0.6910516 50.60517       22.919049     7.678848   57.22222 2012   54     185608  15021 -53.35841  -5.6680040
```

Comment: Your data snippet is probably insufficient to recreate the plot. Are you able to link to a larger dataset so ghat folks here can test and verify possible solutions? Thanks

Comment: @AllanCameron I've added the first 50 rows now, hopefully thats enough to re-create but just let me know if not and i can add more

Comment: Thanks Joe, but your data only includes a single year (they are all 2012), so there is no way to reproduce your problem from it.

Comment: Also, a gam won't run with this size of data set because there are more parameters than data. Could you provide a sample data set that doesn't produce an error when the gam is run? Thanks.

Comment: @AllanCameron Here is a link to the whole dataset, should be able to reproduce now https://drive.google.com/file/d/1o_u18JzvmJGrxk-XNiDhDzbmOZ-l-VJ_/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I had to request access on it

Comment: @AllanCameron Accepted. Let me know if it doesn't work i'll find another way to send. Not 100% sure it will work over google drive

Comment: Yes, that works. Let me have a look for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Producing the smoothed map from a `gam` is a complex affair, so it's probably best to use the data wrangling that takes place inside `plot.gam` - helpfully, this actually return data that we can use to plot in whichever way we like.

First we load your workspace and appropriate packages

```r
load("../../Downloads/TBdata.RData")

library(ggplot2)
library(mgcv)
```

Next we split your data into year groups and carry out your `gam` on each. We then store the data output of the plot for each of the three years and convert it into a data frame. The resulting data frames are bound together into a single large data frame:

```
df <- do.call(rbind, lapply(split(TBdata, TBdata$Year), function(x) {
            p <- plot(gam(TB ~ offset(log(Population)) + 
            s(Indigenous, k = 10, bs = "cr") + 
            s(Urbanisation, k = 10, bs = "cr") +
            s(Density, k = 10, bs = "cr") + 
            Poverty + 
            s(Poor_Sanitation, k = 10, bs = "cr") + 
            Unemployment + 
            Timeliness +
            Region + 
            s(lon, lat), 
              data = x, 
              family = nb(link = 'log')),
            contour.col = 'white', too.far = 0.10, scheme = 2, rug = F)[[5]]
            df <- expand.grid(lon = p$x, lat = p$y)
            df$TB <- p$fit[,1]
            df$Year <- x$Year[1]
            df
            }))
```

Having the data in this format makes the plot itself easy using ggplot:

```r
ggplot(df, aes(lon, lat, z = TB, fill = TB)) +
  geom_tile() +
  geom_contour(color = "white", na.rm = TRUE) +
  facet_grid(.~Year) +
  coord_equal() +
  scale_fill_gradientn(colors = c("red", "yellow", "white"),
                       values = c(0, 0.9, 1),
                       na.value = "white") +
  theme_minimal(base_size = 16)
```

[image]